# Python for Beginners: Roll the dice

Tags: python, while-loop

I have typed the code from this page [PythonForBeginners](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/game-rolling-the-dice/)
but if I execute it,  it will go on forever and not ask me whether I want to roll the dices again. Did I miss something? Should this work?

```
import random
min = 1
max = 6

roll_again = "yes"

while roll_again == "yes" or roll_again == "y":
    print "Rolling the dices..."
    print "The values are...."
    print random.randint(min, max)
    print random.randint(min, max)

    roll_again = raw_input("Roll the dices again?")
```

Comment: If I run this on my machine (first de-indenting the `import random` line) and enter "no", it stops looping. Looks good to me.

Comment: please enter 'no' or anything else other than 'yes' or 'y'. this loop runs based on the user input

Comment: After indenting your first line(`import random`), It works for me? Are you sure your indention is correct?

Comment: Is it possible that `roll_again = raw_input("Roll the dices again?")` isn't in the `while`-loop (does it have the correct indentation?)

Comment: What version of python

Answer (score 0):

Well one way to do it is using a class like this.

```
import random
class RollTheDice(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.min = 1
        self.max = 6
        super(RollTheDice, self).__init__()

    def ask_something(self):
        while True:
            userInput = str(raw_input("Roll Again? Yes or No" + "\n"))
            if (userInput == "Yes" or userInput == 'Y'):
                self.rollDice()
            else:
                print("You didn't type 'Yes' or 'Y' no roll for you. Bye....")
                exit()

    def rollDice(self):
        print "Rolling the dices..."
        print "The values are...."
        print random.randint(self.min, self.max)
        print random.randint(self.min, self.max)

RollTheDiceObject = RollTheDice()
RollTheDiceObject.ask_something()
```

I exit the program if the user doesn't type "Yes" or "Y" with some more code you can make this smarter.

some information on the while loop - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm

Comment: Hey thank you so much! I have a question though. The code became much more complicated now. As I am a Beginner, I can not really understand most of the things you have added. So my question is actually, was the code I used incorrectly?

Comment: I have run your code.The code runs.I wouldn't have had a variable with  Yes to start the while loop.If you look at the class I gave you the while loop starts then the user Input is required.After the input is given then if "Yes" or "Y" then the ask_something function calls the rolldice function, like in your code "rolls the dice". I decided to put in a class just for my own sanity.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been working on the same problem as a beginner. I made a few tweaks to your initial code, set out below, and it worked.

```
 import random
 min = 1
 min = 6

 roll_again = "yes"

 while roll_again == "yes" or roll_again == "y":
   print "You rolled..."
   print random.randint (1,6)
   roll_again = raw_input("Do you want to roll again?")
```

A more efficient and elegant solution would be the following:

```
import random 
repeat = True
while repeat:
  print ("You rolled", random.randint(1,6))
  print ("Do you want to roll again? Y/N")
  repeat = ("y" or "yes") in input().lower()
```